# Programmatically check the device for light notifier

Tags: java, android, notifications, android-notifications

I have an app in which I use notifications with lights. I want to check programmatically if the device has hardware light notifier (the LED next to the front camera and the receiver) or not.
Thanks.

Comment: we don't have any way to know a device has hardware light notification.

Comment: Ok, thank you. It will be cool if they make it possible.